# issues while re-editing text using open-WysiWyg editor

Tags: wysiwyg, innerhtml, document.write

I am using openWysiWyg editor in my website. This is attached to a text-area where I can type in the content and the content is then saved to some php text file with the html tags intact. In the view page on my site i directly include this php file and everything works fine.

Recently I got requests to have some facility to re-edit the already submitted text. For that, I am using the same editor attached to a textarea and I read the contents of the file and pass it to the textarea as . The content get loaded in to the textarea and everything is fine excpet the following issue.
If i try to re-edit something like "**& lt ;pankaj & gt ;**" - upon loading this content in the editor it gets converted to "**< pankaj >< /pankaj >**" upon submitting the new changes.
So I am having two issues - why "**& lt ;**" is getting converted to '**<**' and why is this auto-completion of tags happening.

I figured out the editor does the following steps :

1. take textarea.value in some string
2. use document.write() to copy that value to the texarea's div which in itself is a iframe.
3. upon submitting it takes object.innerHTML to get the contents and then I save it to the disk

the above issues doesnt happen for text - "**i & lt ; 5**".

Comment: Seems like stackoverflow.com also has the same issue whe i RE-edit my already posted thing.. :)

Comment: deliberately providing spaces in the highlighted text to avoid the issue on posing here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

> why "& lt ;" is getting converted to '<'

The editor is disabling the escape character `&lt;` and replacing it with the literal `<`

> why is this auto-completion of tags happening.

The editor is converting the unescaped tag to valid XHTML

> the above issues doesnt happen for text - "i & lt ; 5".

That is a numeric comparison, not markup